# Can I claim a parent receiving Medi-Cal benefits as a dependent on my tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, california, dependents

My mother got her green card this year. She won't work here. All her expenses will be paid by me. Since she is 67 years old, I am planning to apply for [Medi-Cal](http://files.medi-cal.ca.gov/pubsdoco/faq.asp) health coverage for her.

My question is: If she gets Medi-Cal benefits, can I still claim her as a dependent?

Comment: As far as I know, as long as you're paying over 50% of her living expenses, you can claim her as a dependent.

Comment: Although Medi-Cal will count the parent's income for an adult child who is claimed as a dependent. I couldn't find anything for your case. See this [site](http://www.canhr.org/publications/newsletters/Advocate/DearAdvocate/da_2013_4.htm) however.

Answer (score 5):

You will be able to claim your mother as a dependent on your federal taxes so long as she lives with you for the entire year, you provide at least 50% of her income (pay at least 50% of her expenses), she does not file separately, no one else claims her and she is a U.S. citizen, U.S. resident alien, U.S. national, or a resident of Canada or Mexico.

https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000220939

Answer (score 2):

That is my question as well. But when I called MediCal they said if I will claim my parents as my dependents MediCal had to consider my income as their income. So basically they will base my income to their MediCal eligibility & they won’t get approved. But if I take them off as my tax dependents even if I provide everything for them They are considered zero income since they don’t have a job & will get approved. It is really confusing & so sad that I can’t even claim my parents as my dependents even I provide everything for them.